# Sum of emails received in the last 3 months

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table and need to find the 3-month rolling sum of emails sent per customer.

| cust_id | eom_date | email_sent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-30 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-05-31 | null |
| 1 | 2023-04-30 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-03-31 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-02-28 | null |
| 1 | 2023-01-31 | null |
| 2 | 2023-06-30 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-05-31 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-04-30 | 4 |
| 2 | 2023-03-31 | null |
| 2 | 2023-02-28 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-01-31 | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-12-31 | 1 |

This is the desired outcome:

| cust_id | eom_date | email_sent | total_email_3month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-30 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-05-31 | null | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-04-30 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-03-31 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-02-28 | null | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-01-31 | null | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-06-30 | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 2023-05-31 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2023-04-30 | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 2023-03-31 | null | 5 |
| 2 | 2023-02-28 | 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 2023-01-31 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-12-31 | 1 | 1 |

For instance, customer 1 should have a total emails received of 5 on '2023-06-30' (2 + null + 3).

I've tried using partition and ranges in my query but I don't fully understand window functions:

```
SELECT cust_id,
  eom_date, 
  SUM(email_sent),
  SUM(email_sent) OVER (cust_id ORDER BY time_eom_date RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) total_email_3month
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the sum of the sums: `SUM(SUM(email_sent)) OVER (...)`.

Then you want to look at a three months range. Google Bigquery does not support `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '3' MONTH PRECEDING`. You may want to use 90 days instead. As dates don't work, you can use a number (e.g. the Unix date number) then for the range:

```
SELECT
  cust_id,
  eom_date, 
  SUM(email_sent),
  SUM(SUM(email_sent)) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id 
                             ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(eom_date)
                             RANGE BETWEEN 90 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                            ) AS total_email_3month
FROM my_table
GROUP BY cust_id, eom_date
ORDER BY cust_id, eom_date;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can join the table to itself